# Create Custom Image from GCP VM with OS and data disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I set up centos and windows VMs in Google Cloud which has many custom installations and configuration, with 1 boot disk and 4 data disks.

I am trying to create an image of both VMs. Only options I see in google cloud to create an image from disk, snapshot, another image, cloud file or virtual disk.

Looking for some way to create an image at VM level, which I can reuse to create new VMs something similar to custom ami in AWS or custom image in Azure.

The intention is if I create VM out of that image, my new VM will come up with all 5 disks. On GCP console, when I try to create an image, it has no option of using whole VM as a source instead, I can choose single disk as source.

Is there any way or workaround to achieve this in Google Cloud?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. All images are based upon disk drive contents + machine/OS configuration. Google offers images which are just like AWS AMIs. If your goal is to make your images public, that is not allowed at this time except if you join the Marketplace program. For your own project(s) you can create VMs on demand from your own images. Spend some time clarifying your question. Explain what is wrong or missing with Google's current offering and specify the details that you need.

Comment: Thanks, John for your comment. 

I am trying to create a custom image from VM (1 OS disk + 4 data disks). The intention is if I create VM out of that image, my new VM will come up with all 5 disks.

On GCP console, when I try to create an image, it has no option of using whole VM as a source instead, I can choose single disk as source.

Hope I am able to clarify now.

Comment: Google Cloud does not support detailed disk configurations. An image is built from the booting disk drive. Extra data/disk drives would be configured after you build the VM. For extra disk drives, I would not use Images, I would use Snapshots. Faster, cheaper, enables compression, etc.

Comment: Thanks, John. I think this answers my question. So GCP doesn't have the ability to create custom images which I can reuse.

Comment: Edit your question with the new details so that others have a chance to provide answers.

Comment: Yep, I did update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found GCP Instance Templates as a solution to my problem. I can reuse Instance Templates to deploy my custom VMs.